# Can I install games from Steam while my computer is off?

Tags: steam

I know this sounds kind of nooby, but I got my computer a day ago and tried installing CS:GO from Steam, but my internet speed is very slow. I just wanted to know if I could install it while my computer is off, as I don't really want to be sitting here staring at a bar all day.

Comment: I don't think that you can play csgo with "very slow internet". While internet speed doesn't make a big difference on ping, if it is low enough (lower than csgo packet size), you are guaranteed to not be able to play csgo with an acceptable ping.

Answer (score 5):

You can't.
If you want to save energy, just turn off your LCD.

Don't wait until the download is complete, just do your daily life as usual and let your PC do it`s job.

Answer (score 2):

You can't install it if your computer is off, but you can download them in the background while you play other games on Steam.

Go to **Steam>Settings>Downloads** and check **Allow downloads during gameplay**.

Here are some pictures to guide you.

[image]

[image]

I hope this helps you.